# How can I update the beginning balance for each month based on prior month's calculation?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, formula

I am essentially trying to calculate rolling totals in SQL. I have a few different totals (charges, payments, adjustments, bad debt) on each month whose sum needs to be subtracted from the prior month's ending balance. In May, the ending balance was $28,814,788. Given the sum of totals in June (totaling $1,030,927), the ending balance in June should now be $27,783,862 ($28,814,788 - $830,998). This $27,783,862 should now be the beginning balance for July.

I've written the following code. The subquery in the SELECT clause provides May's outstanding balance (the ending balance, $28,814,788) would should be subtracted from the June totals.

```
SELECT  
    CASE    WHEN POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-08-31' THEN 'August - 2019'
            WHEN POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31' THEN 'July - 2019'
            WHEN POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-30' THEN 'June - 2019'
            ELSE 'Other' END as month_year,
    (SELECT sum(OUTSTANDING_AMT)
    FROM ARPB_TRANSACTIONS
    WHERE POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31') as begin_bal,
        sum(CHARGE_AMOUNT)+sum(VOID_AMOUNT) as charge_tot, 
        sum(PAYMENT_AMOUNT) as payment_tot,
        sum(ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT) as adjust_tot,
        sum(ACTIVE_AR_IN_OUT) as bad_debt
FROM F_ARPB_CUBE_ETR_DETAIL
WHERE POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-08-31'
GROUP BY 
    CASE    WHEN POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-08-31' THEN 'August - 2019'
            WHEN POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31' THEN 'July - 2019'
            WHEN POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-30' THEN 'June - 2019'
            ELSE 'Other' END
```

Expected results would be: [DESIRED OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1MlG.png)

Answer (score 0):

So, I actually figured out an answer to my own question. I took a few steps.

First, I decided to organize things a bit by adding a column to reflect the sum of charges, payments, adjustments and bad_debt. This comes in handy later for the running total. It felt a little "hacky" but, I'm just learning, so whatever.

```
sum(CHARGE_AMOUNT)+sum(VOID_AMOUNT)+sum(PAYMENT_AMOUNT)+
    sum(ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT)+sum(ACTIVE_AR_IN_OUT) as sum_of_values
```

Second, I created a running total. This was a challenge initially because I couldn't reference the month and year unless I gave it an alias as month_year and placed in a subquery in the FROM clause.

```
FROM 
    (SELECT 
CASE    WHEN POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-30' THEN 'June - 2019'
        WHEN POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31' THEN 'July - 2019'
        WHEN POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-08-31' THEN 'August - 2019'
        ELSE 'Other' END as month_year,
        (SELECT sum(OUTSTANDING_AMT)
    FROM ARPB_TRANSACTIONS
    WHERE POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31') as beginning_balance,
    sum(CHARGE_AMOUNT)+sum(VOID_AMOUNT) as charge_tot, 
    sum(PAYMENT_AMOUNT) as payment_tot,
    sum(ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT) as adjustment_tot,
    sum(ACTIVE_AR_IN_OUT) as bad_debt_tot,
    sum(CHARGE_AMOUNT)+sum(VOID_AMOUNT)+sum(PAYMENT_AMOUNT)+
    sum(ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT)+sum(ACTIVE_AR_IN_OUT) as sum_of_values 
FROM F_ARPB_CUBE_ETR_DETAIL 
WHERE POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-08-31'
GROUP BY CASE   
    WHEN POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-30' THEN 'June - 2019'
    WHEN POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31' THEN 'July - 2019'
    WHEN POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-08-31' THEN 'August - 2019'
    ELSE 'Other' END ) as x
```

Third, this then allowed me to specifically reference "month_year" in my running total expression:

```
 SELECT month_year, beginning_balance,charge_tot, payment_tot, adjustment_tot, bad_debt_tot, sum_of_values, SUM(sum_of_values) OVER (ORDER BY month_year desc) as running_total
```

Last, instead of a running (sum) total, I actually needed a running subtraction from the prior months running total (that being the "beginning_balance" less the "sum_of_values") so to do that I just modified the above expression like:

```
SELECT  month_year, beginning_balance,charge_tot, payment_tot, adjustment_tot, bad_debt_tot, sum_of_values, beginning_balance-SUM(sum_of_values) OVER (ORDER BY month_year desc) as running_total
```

So here's the final query:

```
SELECT  month_year, beginning_balance,charge_tot, payment_tot, adjustment_tot, bad_debt_tot, sum_of_values, beginning_balance-SUM(sum_of_values) OVER (ORDER BY month_year desc) as running_total
FROM 
    (SELECT 
CASE    WHEN POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-30' THEN 'June - 2019'
        WHEN POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31' THEN 'July - 2019'
        WHEN POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-08-31' THEN 'August - 2019'
        ELSE 'Other' END as month_year,
        (SELECT sum(OUTSTANDING_AMT)
    FROM ARPB_TRANSACTIONS
    WHERE POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31') as beginning_balance,
    sum(CHARGE_AMOUNT)+sum(VOID_AMOUNT) as charge_tot, 
    sum(PAYMENT_AMOUNT) as payment_tot,
    sum(ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT) as adjustment_tot,
    sum(ACTIVE_AR_IN_OUT) as bad_debt_tot,
    sum(CHARGE_AMOUNT)+sum(VOID_AMOUNT)+sum(PAYMENT_AMOUNT)+
    sum(ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT)+sum(ACTIVE_AR_IN_OUT) as sum_of_values 
FROM F_ARPB_CUBE_ETR_DETAIL 
WHERE POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-08-31'
GROUP BY CASE   
    WHEN POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-30' THEN 'June - 2019'
    WHEN POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31' THEN 'July - 2019'
    WHEN POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-08-31' THEN 'August - 2019'
    ELSE 'Other' END ) as x
ORDER BY month_year desc
```

[Final Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRblP.jpg)

Comment: Note that using an inclusive upper bound means you need to take special care around February (depending on how you get the end-of-month date).  Using an exclusive upper-bound for the _next_ month (eg, `WHEN POST_DATE >= '2019-06-01' AND POST_DATE < '2019-07-01'`) makes that easier, plus solves any issues if it turns out `POST_DATE` also has time.  You may find that using a calendar table will also simplify things.

Comment: Ah great points thank you, I will check out the calendar table